# Should I use comma or not before "wearing"?

Tags: punctuation, participle-clauses

Recently I saw a sentence like this:

> Did a guy just go by here wearing a hat?

In my opinion, it should be something like

> Did a guy wearing a hat just go by here?

I was thinking it should be added a comma between "here" and "wearing", and the participle clause (wearing a hat) should have modified "guy". So now I am wondering if this sentence is correct or maybe the author leave out a comma in this sentence?

Comment: Please note that in English it is a grammar mistake to use "i" as a pronoun. The first person pronoun "I" should always be capitalised.

Answer (score 1):

> "Did a guy just go by here wearing a hat?"

This is correct English although you probably don't need 'here'. The phrase "wearing a hat" is adverbial to the verb "go". It has the same structure as:

"Did a guy just go by here slowly?"

You would not put a comma before "slowly" and you do not put a comma before "wearing."

> **Adverbial**
>
> > "Did a guy just go by here slowly?"
> >
> > "Did a guy just go by here wearing a hat?"
>
> **Adjectival**
>
> > Did a slow guy just go by here?
> >
> > Did a hat-wearing guy  just go by here?

Comment: I still don't get it..I think that "wearing a hat" should function as an adjective modifying the guy.but you was like(it's adverbial to the verb"go")...but I have never seen such case..I mean could a participial clause be functioned as an adverb? I personally think that the reason author didn't use comma is because there is only one subject (guy) in this sentence.so there is no need to add comma.for example, like (he sent some music to her,thinking that she will like it),in such case, "thinking that she will like it" functions as an adjective

Comment: Oh..I was wrong..as you said above,at times it acts as adverb..for example(the woman improved her health running five miles a day).and this sentence definitely fits in with your explanation...

Comment: So, bump it up or checkmark it!